# How to resize images to fit my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have images of different sizes and I am trying to use them as a background on a canvas.

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>js</title>
</head>
<body onLoad='init2()'>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
   </canvas>

<!-- This image will be displayed on the canvas -->   
<img id="myImage" src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/bareconf-140329111624-phpapp02/95/draft-scientific-paper-1-638.jpg?cb=1396091812" style = "display: none">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I resize all the images to my canvas size which is fixed?
Here is the full [code](https://jsfiddle.net/sukchguj/2/).

When I change to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5bFz.png), it is not resizing to my canvas dimensions.

Which is better, to resize all my images or my canvas?

Comment: Do you care about maintaining the aspect ratio of your image?

Comment: "which is better, to resize all my images or my canvas?"
Depends what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *4rth* and *5th* parameter of `drawImage` to define target width and height of the source image.

You can use:

> void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);

If you provide `dx, dy` as 0, 0 (as you are already providing in your example code) and `dWidth` and `dHeight` to canvas width and height, the source image will stretch to whole canvas.

If your source image has different aspect ratio and stretching it behind whole canvas disturbs it, you can use the following version:

> void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth,
>   dHeight);

`sx, sy` are source image's start *x*, start *y* coordinate (which implicitly in previous version was 0, 0) and `sWidth, sHeight` are source image's width and height you want to pick and place on canvas.

So using start x, start y and width and height of source image, you can smartly choose a partition of source image so that when it stretches on whole canvas, aspect ratio should not get distorted.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).